# Why firebase are not deploying url?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy firebase functions. It must deploy some url function: https://us-central1...etc, but there is no url.

I tried to change my location in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) resource location to nam5 (us-central).

```
C:\users\me\desktop\functions: firebase deploy
=== Deploying to 'functions-777'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

+  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/functions-777/overview
```

I expect the output of this url for checking in postman https://us-central1/cloudfunctions/helloworld

Comment: The output you're showing suggests that you haven't defined any functions at all in your index.js file.  You would at least see one line per function as the code gets deployed.

Comment: hm, actually i wrote this:
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello world!");
 });

Comment: Can you check you console? firebase.google.com.  Look at the functions tab and see if you can see your function listed.  The URL will be in the function if it's an http function.   Typically the application name is in the URL as well.  The URL you have looks too generic.

Comment: at the functions tab there is no functions lol...

Comment: Did you save the file?  Are you editing the correct file?  Have you tried creating a new project workspace to make sure everything is set correctly?

Comment: Okay, just saved now and it works.